# Scripting in Excel -- Highlighting like values

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will basically highlight like values in column A the same color and alternate between a blue and white coloring. Therefore, exact values are grouped together by color.

Hope this makes sense? At this moment I am doing the highlighting manually (but there are 12000+ rows so thats not a smart idea). I am not so great with VBA yet and am still trying to learn more.

So basically this macro will check is the value in cell x of column A is the same of cell x+1 in the same column; if it is then they will be highlighted white. Now if cell x+2 is not the same value as x but cell x+2 and x+3 are the same values, they will be highlighted in the blue color. I need teh color to spread through the WHOLE ROW

Here is a visual(imagine the whole row as colored):

[image: VISUAL]

Comment: do you *need* vba ? or will conditional formatting be ok ?

Comment: @user1281385 anything that is quick, macro would be better

Comment: why ? They are slower than conditional formats

Comment: @user1281385 I figured because of the amount of data... but what conditional format do you suggest

Answer (score 0):

This will highlight the second cell in the column.  The color might now be the extact color you want though.

**EDIT2**: added the definition for testcell1, first,Second and Added Report as worksheet code

**edit 3**:  changed <> to =

```
Sub runthis()


'Dim row As Integer

Dim TestCell As String
Dim first As String
Dim Second As String

Dim TestCell1 As String
Dim lastcell As Integer

Sheets("sheet1").Select

Dim Report As Worksheet
Set Report = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1")


lastcell = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

For row = 1 To lastcell
    TestCell = "A" & CInt(row)
    TestCell1 = "A" & (CInt(row) + 1)
    first = Range(TestCell).Value
    Second = Range(TestCell1).Value

    If first = Second Then
        Report.Cells(row, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    End If
Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a compilation error as TestCell1 does not exist.. what did you mean for it to be? as well as "first" .. its just not compiling

Comment: I have 2010... when I had the Public Sub line to the code, i get an "invalid quantifier" compile error

Comment: Please be sure to mark this as the "Accepted' answer and if it was useful.

Comment: I will mark it once it works, promise... however I am not getting a "Subscript out of range" error with "Sheets("sheet1").Select" highlighted

Comment: Is your sheet called `Sheet1`? That is the default name. You need to change it to whatever your sheet is named.... I just noticed that the `sheet1` in the code has a lowercase `s`. You might try changing that to an uppercase `S` although it worked fine for me with the lowercase letter.

Comment: Also, this is just highlighting the last of the duplicates and unique values.. and thus does not do what I want. Please view the visual again and let me know how we can work towards that.. thank you!

Comment: this works better and I added the line " Report.Cells(row + 1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3" to the Then of first = second... however, all the duplicates come out red.. but I want that the first group be red and the other group of duplicates be white.. and so on and so forth . IS there a way to do that?